# How to escape jQuery script in Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

javascript code in HTML file below

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
     .
     .
     .
    for (var i = 0, l = 100; i < l; i++) {
       list.push($.extend({}, sampleData[(Math.floor(Math.random() * 
       sampleData.length))]));
    }
```

thymeleaf error message is that

> Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could
>   not parse as expression: "Math.floor(Math.random() *
>   sampleData.length)" (template: "gridTest" - line 165, col 63)

how do I resolve this ?
thanks.

Comment: That's odd. I guess thymeleaf is confused by "[/...". Try adding /*<![CDATA[* / after the opening script-tag and /*]]>*/ before the closing script-tag. https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart --- I added a extra space after a * for comment-formating reasons.

Comment: I highly recommend if you create a separate JS file for each html page, then you wont have this problem and code will be cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text `[(...)]` is a variation on [JavaScript inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining) -- which is why Thymeleaf is trying to parse `[(Math.floor(Math.random() * sampleData.length))]` as a Thymeleaf expression (and consequently throwing the error).

In any case, the parenthesis around the `Math.floor(...)` expression are unneeded, so you can remove them and the Thymeleaf will work.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    .
    .
    .

    for (var i = 0, l = 100; i < l; i++) {
       list.push($.extend({}, sampleData[Math.floor(Math.random() * sampleData.length)]));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: As you say, problem is "[("  

    "sampleData[(Math.floor(Math.~"   => error  
   "sampleData[Math.floor(Math.~"   => no error  
and   
   "sampleData[ (Math.floor(Math.~"   => no error (just add one space)

thank you